# r flag rows in 1st dataframe if the date is between two dates in second dataframe

Tags: r, date, dplyr, grouping, inner-join

I have two datasets. First dataset has two date columns (Start, Stop) for each ID. Sometimes it can contain multiple Start-Stop Dates for each ID.

Dataset1

```
  Id    Code    Start        Stop
  431   279     2017-11-15   2019-08-15
  431   578     2019-09-15   2021-01-15
  832   590     2008-04-15   2020-05-15
  832   519     2020-06-15   2021-04-15
```

The second dataset has Id and many time stamped rows per ID, like this below

```
  Id   Weight   Date
  431  12.23    2018
  832  15.12    2020
  832   6.78    2020
  832   4.27    2007
```

My goal is to create a column `InBetween` that indicates "Yes" if the row in 2nd dataset is between the two dates in the first dataset or "No" if the rows in the 2nd dataset is not between the two dates in first dataset, with other columns from 1st dataset like this.

```
    Id   Weight   Date   Between  Code  Start        Stop
    431  12.23    2018   Yes      279   2017-11-15   2019-08-15  
    832  15.12    2020   Yes      590   2008-04-15   2020-05-15
    832   6.78    2020   Yes      590   2008-04-15   2020-05-15
    832   4.27    2007   No       NA    NA           NA
```

I could do this with for loops, but I prefer any solution using dplyr, innerjoin or other options without forloops. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty messy but you may try,

```
df2 %>%
  full_join(df1, by = "Id") %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(ISOdate(Date,1,1)),
         Start = as.Date(Start),
         Stop = as.Date(Stop)) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Between = between(Date, Start, Stop)) %>%
  group_by(Id, Date) %>%
  mutate(check = any(Between)) %>%
  filter(!(Between == FALSE& check == TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(Start = ifelse(check, Start, NA), 
         Stop = ifelse(check, Stop, NA),
         Code = ifelse(check, Code, NA)) %>%
  distinct() %>% select(-check)


     Id Weight Date        Code Start  Stop Between
  <int>  <dbl> <date>     <int> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  
1   431  12.2  2018-01-01   279 17485 18123 TRUE   
2   832  15.1  2020-01-01   590 13984 18397 TRUE   
3   832   6.78 2020-01-01   590 13984 18397 TRUE   
4   832   4.27 2007-01-01    NA    NA    NA FALSE
```

Comment: this will do it. For some reason the dates come out as numeric and I had to rewire them again into proper format, but this does the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat shorter version that also achieves what you are after.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
         ~Id, ~Code,       ~Start,        ~Stop,
        431L,  279L, "2017-11-15", "2019-08-15",
        431L,  578L, "2019-09-15", "2021-01-15",
        832L,  590L, "2008-04-15", "2020-05-15",
        832L,  519L, "2020-06-15", "2021-04-15"
        )
df2 <- tibble::tribble(
          ~Id, ~Weight, ~Date,
         431L,   12.23, 2018L,
         832L,   15.12, 2020L,
         832L,    6.78, 2020L,
         832L,    4.27, 2007L
         )

df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(Start = ymd(Start),
         Stop = ymd(Stop))

df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date, truncated = 2L))

full_join(df1, df2) %>% 
  mutate(Between = case_when( (Date %within% interval(ymd(Start), ymd(Stop))) == TRUE ~ TRUE,
                              TRUE ~ FALSE))
#> Joining, by = "Id"
#> # A tibble: 8 × 7
#>      Id  Code Start      Stop       Weight Date       Between
#>   <int> <int> <date>     <date>      <dbl> <date>     <lgl>  
#> 1   431   279 2017-11-15 2019-08-15  12.2  2018-01-01 TRUE   
#> 2   431   578 2019-09-15 2021-01-15  12.2  2018-01-01 FALSE  
#> 3   832   590 2008-04-15 2020-05-15  15.1  2020-01-01 TRUE   
#> 4   832   590 2008-04-15 2020-05-15   6.78 2020-01-01 TRUE   
#> 5   832   590 2008-04-15 2020-05-15   4.27 2007-01-01 FALSE  
#> 6   832   519 2020-06-15 2021-04-15  15.1  2020-01-01 FALSE  
#> 7   832   519 2020-06-15 2021-04-15   6.78 2020-01-01 FALSE  
#> 8   832   519 2020-06-15 2021-04-15   4.27 2007-01-01 FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>